# How do I switch to using Facebook instead of OpenID while signing in to StackExchange without changing my username?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, user-accounts

I had originally signed up with StackExchange (back when it was only StackOverflow) with OpenID, since that was the cool--and in case of SO, the only--thing to do. As time has passed, so has the coolness of OpenID. Now, on most sites, you either sign in with Twitter or Facebook or an old fashioned local account system. In fact, StackExchange is now the only network for which I use my OpenID. Everyone else has moved on.

I know StackExchange sites let you sign in using a multitude of accounts including Facebook, but my question is: How do I associate my Facebook account with my existing StackExchange account and sign in using Facebook from there on?

I don't want to create a new username. I don't want to lose my rep points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the information on Meta Stack Overflow under "[How do I change my OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)":

> This is documented on the [Stack
>   Overflow
>   blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/).
>
> Go to your user page and click **add
>   openid** or **change openid**.
>
> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/openid-multiple-association-2-new.png
>
> Note that once both are populated, the
>   **primary** OpenId will be overwritten if you associate another OpenID.
>
> You can use the [swap] link (not
>   pictured) to switch your primary and
>   secondary OpenID at will.
>
> After changing, <s>beware that copying
>   your profile to other accounts [does
>   not copy the OpenID
>   details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/copy-profile-from-stack-overflow-didnt-copy-alternate-openid/6018#6018).</s> you might want to click on "Copy Stack
>   Overflow login credentials to all
>   Stack Exchange sites"
>
> [image]

Comment: I've been staring at that link for months and I just never clicked it, because it's misleading. I didn't want to add another OpenID, so I never even thought of clicking on it. I really wish that link gets changed to "Add account" or "Add new provider" or something a little general.

Comment: Good feedback. To be fair though, you could have added a second OpenID and just stopped using the old one, but had it for backup. Still would have solved your problem.

Comment: The problem here is the use of the term 'OpenID' as a general, any kind of authentication system. Granted, Facebook does support the OpenID system, but Facebook Connect isn't OpenID, and that's what threw me off.

Comment: I agree. The term openid for adding a email/password combo doesn't make sense. It should say 'Change credentials'. Even after reading the above it took me a while because I *knew* I didn't want an openid, so I clicked 'edit' which didn't have the correct options. In the end I set up another account from scratch on another SO site and used the copy credentials option.

Answer (score 2):

On your profile you will see this link next at top left of the bio area:

> add openid

Click that.

You'll then be prompted to fill out a secondary OpenID.

After you're done you'll be able to log into your account with your original OpenID credential or the newly added.