# Can I add an SE OpenID to my existing profile?

Tags: support, openid, user-profiles

Due to some complications signing in this morning with my Google account, I would like to register for a Stack Exchange OpenID account and add it to my profile.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2839/how-do-i-switch-to-using-facebook-instead-of-openid-while-signing-in-to-stackexch/2840#2840

Comment: @random as far as I can tell, that question only applies if I've already created a SE OpenID account, which I haven't.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do that from the add account screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and click on [`Register`](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register).
- Create a Stack Exchange OpenID account
- Follow the directions explained in [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers) to add a new OpenID
- Choose your new Stack Exchange OpenID as the provider to add

Comment: I'll assume this works properly, but I'm having the same problem with the SE OpenID login as I was with Google's.  Something weird about the hotel connection I'm on right now.